# BootStrap Nav Button Link not Working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The green "Blog" button on the top points to the right location, but when clicked, there is no response. It seems it's not a z-index issue. It seems to be a conflict with the jQuery nav, but the solution here is very unclear.

Here is the JS: http://pastebin.com/JuJwKdSZ
and JS #2: http://pastebin.com/VDpViTqP

Here is the HTML: http://pastebin.com/BYuehZnU

Comment: Please post your code here, rather than giving a link to the site with the error.

Comment: My apologies, I've edited it.

Comment: That's ok, people don't like visiting unknown sites so you are likely to get more people answering your question.
It also helps the community if anyone else has the same problem in the future and you have already fixed the problem on your site, they cannot see what the original problem was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I may have found the answer. It is to do with the plugin you are using: [OnePageNav](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav)

This handles all clicks on links on the page. There is a filter ability on that plugin though, when you initialize the instance of one page, you can include a filter of a class name and add that class name to your external link like so:

html

```
<a id="blog" class="btn button navbar-btn white external" href="/blog"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Blog</a>
```

Change this in the first js file (line 44)

```
filter: '',
```

to this

```
filter: 'external',
```